# Correct proof for the Hoare triple?

Tags: logic

I have recently started with studying Hoare triples and I am a total noob so you will be aware of it. I was assigned to prove the partial correctness of the program, whose name is Max:

```
i=0;
m=a[0];
while(i!=k)  {
    if(a[i]>=m)  {
        m=a[i];
    } else {
        m=m;
    }
    i=i+1;
}
```

And the specification for this program is $(|k>0|)Max(|∀j(0≤j<k→m≥a[j])|)$, where k means the number of elements in the array a and m the maximum value in the array a.

I have already tried to prove this on my own hand. Here is my attempt to prove the Hoare triple:

```
(|k>0|) Pre-condition
i=0;    
m=a[0];
(|Inv(i,m)|)    Implied

while(i!=k)  {
    (|Inv(i,m)∧i≠k|)    Invariant ∧ Guard
    if(a[i]≥m)  {
        (|Inv(i,m)∧a[i]≥m|) If-statement
        m=a[i];
        (|Inv(i+1,m)|)  Implied
    } else { 
        (|Inv(i,m)∧¬(a[i]≥m)|)  If-statement
        m=m;
        (|Inv(i+1,m)|)  Implied
    }
    i=i+1;
    (|Inv(i,m)|)    Assignment
}
(|Inv(i,m)∧¬(i≠k)|) Partial-while
(|Inv(k,m)|)        Post-condition
```

My chosen loop invariant for this while loop is $Inv(i,m)=∀j(0≤j<i→m≥a[j])$. I hope this is a correct loop invariant.

The first thing I am not that sure about is if I have identified all (correct) proof obligations with the implied assertions that I have made in the proof. Second thing is that I am not sure about if the first 4 rows are correct. I have reasoned that when i=0 and m=a[0], then it must always be true due to the fact that you are aware about only one element so far and that element is supposed to be the current max value, which is specified by the assertion on the fourth row.

I have really struggled on this assignment and I would appreciate a lot if you could criticize my proof of the Hoare triple and explain why some parts (or even the proof itself) doesn't work at all.

If something is not clear, then please tell me so I can explain further.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: There is another thing I am also unsure about: how do I emphasize in my proof that k>0 will always hold before the first loop in the program? It feels like that assuming the invariant to be hold after the executed instructions on second- and third row will hold no matter what since $∀j(0≤j<i→m≥a[j])$ will be always true because $0≤j<i$, when $i=0$, is false.